# why do my UILabels not appear in the right spaces

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

I have a game. I am loading 3 image views with label objects. Then I load 5, and then 7. Just yesterday I had the same issue, and I found the answer to be making the autoresizing mask on the labels to none. Well, I did that, it fixed it, but now the issue is back today. This is confusing, and I have no clue how to fix it.

My question is, why is this still happening if i've already done that? and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
  // random word from array of object
    NSString *randomWord = [self.objects objectAtIndex:randomObject];

    [self.imageViews[i] addSubview:self.labels[i]];
    [self.labels[i] setCenter:[self.imageViews[i] center]];

    // all labels setting text and alignment
    [self.labels[i] setText:randomWord];
    [self.labels[i] setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

    // adding words to alphabetical array
    [self.alphabeticalWords addObject:randomWord];
    NSLog(@"%@", randomWord);
    //NSLog(@"%@", self.alphabeticalWords);

    [self.labels[i] sizeToFit];
    [self.labels[i] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
    [self.imageViews[i] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imageViews[i] addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

and here is the issue

[image]

any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is your use if the view hierarchy and `center`. You are adding the labels as subviews to the image views and then using `center` to try to overlay them. The definition of center is:

`The center is specified within the coordinate system of its superview and is measured in points. Setting this property changes the values of the frame properties accordingly.`

Setting the center of a subview to the center of its superview will not necessarily behave the way you want because they are not sitting in the same coordinate space.

You should be using the `bounds` of the image view which is what represents its internal coordinate space. What you probably want to do is something like this instead:

```
[self.labels[i] setCenter:CGPointMake((self.imageViews[i].bounds.size.width / 2), (self.imageViews[i].bounds.size.height / 2)];
```

Comment: i typed that, but it still is behaving weird. is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: It's doing the exact same thing that is in the image in my question. it didn't change what happens for some reason. Would calling sizeToFit on the labels cause it to act that way?

Comment: How are you positioning all of this stuff in the first place? Can you provide that code?

Comment: I have the labels set up in my storyboard where i want them. I then check if my variable self.carsLevel, which is what controls the information on the screen is either 3, 5, or 7. If it's 3, i make labels/imageviews 4-7 hidden. If self.carsLevel is 5, i make labels/imageviews 6-7 hidden. And if self.carsLevel is 7, I make none of them hidden. Should I just set up the locations in code?

Comment: Did you turn autolayout off in the storyboard? If autolayout is on, using autoresizingmasks and directly modifying the position (via frame or center) won't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56078/discussion-between-user2277872-and-dima).